# more then the array length go 0 , if below 0 go back the last length

Tags: jquery

```
function FontMenu(font_number){
  // Font family
var fontFamily = ["Arial", "Georgia", "Crushed", "Trochut", "Anton", "Monoton"];

var counter = font_number;

this.font = fontFamily;
this.counter = counter;
}

FontMenu.prototype._Left = function (){
  this.counter--;
  alert(this.font[this.counter]);
}

FontMenu.prototype._Right = function (){
  this.counter++;
  alert(this.font[this.counter]);
}
```

i have left button and right button , when user click it will check the array, lets said the font_number was 0 , and the fontfamily length is 6 , when i press right, this.counter ++ , when it over the fontfamily length it wont go back to 0, same as this.counter -- when it go 0 i want it to go to the last fontFamily length.

sorry if my question isit clear. thank for helping , simple as if more then 6 go back to 0 , if below then 0 go back to the last length.

but is there any simple way without using if statement ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- you can use modular arithmetic.

Incrementing is simple: add one to the counter, then take the remainder of the result modulo the length of the list.

```
FontMenu.prototype._Right = function() {
  this.counter = (this.counter + 1) % this.font.length;
};
```

Decrementing is almost the same, except you subtract one from the counter. You also need to add the length of the list to ensure that the left operand is non-negative. Take the result modulo the list length as before.

```
FontMenu.prototype._Left = function() {
  this.counter = (this.counter + this.font.length - 1) % this.font.length;
};
```

Some resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

Comment: Sorry i check the this.counter , it keep adding 10 , lets say my font_number = 0 , when i click it become 01, and then more click it become 001. i think it add text not number how i fix it